# Word cloud in asp.net, filtering common words

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, tag-cloud

I want to develop a word cloud for a project I'm working on. My application is connected to a database which holds a series of questions. What I need to do is pull all questions from the database, discard commonly used words (and,to,a, etc) then render the remaining words in a word cloud. I've read through a few tutorials but they've went completely over my head. So I was wondering if anyone has developed anything similar in the past and if so, how they went about it or what resources they used to help them.

Im using web forms with C# and an SQL Server database

Many thanks.

Comment: you need to break it in few steps. 1. Get you question from database. 2. create a list of commonly used words 3. create a loop and filter these loops from what you get from database. 4. display it in a control.

Comment: Thanks for the response Zaki. I can do the first two steps, the third and fourth are where it gets a bit tricky. I'll have a read through a few more examples and see if they help.